# What is wrong with the following formation of a killing form or metric matrix for sl(2,r)?

Tags: matrices, metric-spaces, lie-groups, lie-algebras

For sl(2,r) take the generators $m_1\!=\!\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right], m_2\!=\!\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right]
,m_3\!=\!\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\1&0\end{array}\right]$
so nonzero structure cst's are $C_{1,2}^2\!=\!-C_{2,1}^2\!=\!2,\;C_{1,3}^3\!=\!-C_{3,1}^3\!=\!-2,\;C_{2,3}^1\!=\!-C_{3,2}^1\!=\!1$ from which obtain a killing or
metric matrix $\;gm\!=\!\left[\begin{array}{cc}8&0&0\\0&0&4\\0&4&0\end{array}
\right]$ which is non-singular and according text book(s) cannot be true for sl(2,r).

Comment: What cannot be true? The Killing form is certainly non-singular for a simple Lie algebra (Cartan's criterion!), and that looks like it, at least up to scalar multiples. What is the problem?

Comment: as i recall I read that it is singular for non-compact groups. Also i would think the fact that sl(2,r) is isomorphic to su(1,1) which is isomorphic to so(2,1) may be significant.

Answer (score 6):

The Killing form of any semisimple Lie algebra is always non-degenerate (and as stated by @paul_garrett this is Cartan's criterion for semisimplicity). What you remember is probaly that the killing form is (negative) definite only for compact Lie algebras. And the form that you obtain for $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$ indeed is indefinite (since the determinant is negative).

Comment: ok but it's a little odd that i have never seen any remark about why some isomorphic lie groups cannot have isomorphic lie algebras which is true in this case.

Comment: Isomorphic Lie groups always have isomorphic Lie algebras. I don't see why the example discussed here contradicts this. ($\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$ and $\mathfrak{so}(2,1)$ are not compact, so no problem there.

Comment: in that case then the killing form for su(1,1) would also be nonsingular since it is nonsingular for su(2,r)

Comment: So if u are saying so(2,1) is simple or semi-simple and killing form matrix not singular then this may be the explanation because I assumed and thought i read that so(3,1) is not simple nor semi-simple and killing form matrix was singular ? Is that correct ? And if so i just assumed the same was true of so(2,1) being also non-compact.

Comment: $su(1,1,)$, $so(2,1)$ and $sl(2,\mathbb R)$ all are real forms forms of $sl(2,\mathbb C)\cong so(3,\mathbb C)$ (and so are $su(2)$ and $so(3)$). All these real forms are simple and hence have non-degenerate Killing form. The only compact Lie algebras among these are $su(2)\cong so(3)$, these have negative definite Killing form. For all the others, the Killing form is indefnite.

Comment: yes i was just about ready to delete that last comment after some more reading and directly calculating a killing form for 6 generators of so(3,1) myself though haven't done so quite yet and will likely find it is not singular also :so i think u were correct as i was mixing up degenerate with indefinite- like not negative nor positive definite but still non singular. The semi-simple means no abelian normal factor groups ? I am also going to calculate it for sl(3,r) which i would think will have a singular killing form matrix but not sure.

Comment: On the group level, semisimple means that any abelian normal subgroup is discrete. All $sl$'s,. $so$'s and $su$'s are semisimple and hence have non-degenerate Killing form.

Comment: so(3,1) has 6 generators so why isn't the killing form as a matrix a 6 by 6 matrix ? since that is inherent in the definition of killing form. So why is the killing form only a 4 by 4 matrix for so(3,1) ?

Comment: I never claimed anything about $6\times 6$ or $4\times 4$. The algebra $so(3,1)$ (as all real forms of $so(4,C)\cong sl(2,C)\times sl(2,C)$) is not simple but semisimple. So if you choose your basis well, the matrix of the Killing form will be block diagonal with two $3\times 3$-blocks, but still non-singular.

Comment: I know u didn't say I calculated killing form in basis it was diagonal with 3 1's and 3 -1's so my point is that is a 6 by 6 matrix and since the killing form and metric tensor are the same then something is off because in all my readings the metric tensor for so(3,1) or lorentz group is 4 by 4 with 3 1's and one -1 along the diagonal or minus that. I also calculated a killing form for sl(3,r) and got diagonal 8x8 matrix with 5 1's and 3 -1's so it's nonsingular also. Anyway the discrepancy is with .so(3,1) unless the standard 4x4 one is different and unrelated to lie group?